# Data not printing correct

Tags: python, linux, dictionary, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

When running a data streaming sub-process against a multiprocessing, after printing a single element in the dictionary program freezes,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess,time, timeit
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import re, os, pprint, math
from collections import defaultdict

Dict = {}
count = defaultdict(int)
queueVar = Queue()

def __ReadRX__(RX_info):
    lines = iter(RX_info.stdout.readline, "")
    try:
        start = time.clock()
        for line in lines:
            if re.match(r"^\d+.*$",line):
                splitline = line.split()
                del splitline[1:4]
                identifier = splitline[1]
                count[identifier] += 1
                end = time.clock()
                timing = round((end - start) * 10000, 100)
                dlc = splitline[2]
                hexbits = splitline[3:]
                Dict[identifier] = [dlc, hexbits, count[identifier],int(timing)]
                start = end 
                for identifier,hexbits in Dict.items():
                    queueVar.put(Dict)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

procRX = subprocess.Popen('receivetest -f=/dev/pcan32'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    munchCan = Process(target=__ReadRX__, args=(procRX,))
    munchCan.start()
    #munchCan.join()
    printDict = queueVar.get()
    for i in range(len(printDict)):
        print printDict
```

I know if if I print from `__ReadRX__`  it prints a constant stream however when trying to print from outside of the function I only get a single entry in the dictionary.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something but I only see one line printing anything and no loop making it run more than one time.

Comment: @jimmy, Thanks for point that out, I have added a loop for the print but this still only prints one, it should print every entry in the dictionary, which in theory should go on forever

Comment: Try also adding a short sleep between each print or else your second thread will never have time to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following at the top:

```
from time import sleep
```

then after the print statement add:

```
sleep(1)
```

this will make the script wait for 1 second. You can adjust that number as necessary.